# Can not receive message from queues when the Exchange object's type is "direct"

Tags: celery, exchange-server, kombu

When I change the "direct" type to "fanout" or "topic", it is work.But the "direct" type is not work.

- I wrote according to the example of the official website.
- And I tried deleting the code => "from **future** import absolute_import, unicode_literals".But it still not work.

---

- queues.py

  - it is work if I change type to 'fanout' or 'topic'.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from kombu import Queue, Exchange

exchange = Exchange('demo_exchange', type='topic')
demo_queues = [
    Queue('one', exchange, routing_key='o'),
    Queue('two', exchange, routing_key='t'),
    Queue('three', exchange, routing_key='th'),
]
```

- worker.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from kombu.mixins import ConsumerMixin
from kombu import Connection

from queues import demo_queues

class Worker(ConsumerMixin):

    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def get_consumers(self, Consumer, channel):
        return [Consumer(queues=demo_queues, accept=['pickle', 'json'], callbacks=[self.on_task])]

    def on_task(self, body, message):
        args = body['args']
        func = body['func']
        print(args, func)

        func()
        message.ack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection('redis://localhost:6379/0') as conn:
        try:
            worker = Worker(conn)
            worker.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('bye')
```

- client.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from kombu.pools import producers

from queues import exchange

priority_to_routing_key = {
    'high': 'o',
    'mid': 't',
    'low': 'th',
}


def send_tasks(conn, func, args, priority='high'):
    data = {'func': func, 'args': args}

    with producers[conn].acquire(block=True) as producer:
        routing_key = priority_to_routing_key[priority]
        producer.publish(data,
                         serializer='pickle',
                         exchange=exchange,
                         declare=[exchange],
                         routing_key=routing_key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kombu import Connection
    from tasks import func_task

    connection = Connection('redis://localhost:6379/0')
    send_tasks(connection, func=func_task, args=('test hello'), priority='mid')
```

- tasks.py

```py
def func_task(n='hello'):
    print(n, '---====')
```

I hope to work out this.

Comment: When I use rabbitmq, it worked.   :)